# WMS Image Services Do Not Display

Tags: arcgis-10.0, wms, imagery

We recently upgraded to Image Server 10.0.1 and in the process our WMS Image Services quit displaying. The connection to them works in ArcCatalog, but it never displays.  If I preview the service it gives coordinates but no image. I will admit that we had this problem when we originally created them and I figured out the problem...but that was over a year ago and I can't remember that far back. The XML can be viewed here: https://maps.sjcounty.net/ArcGIS/services/2009_SJCounty_1ft_IS/ImageServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The capabilities document has links in it that use the internal name of your server:

http://macewindu:8080/ArcGIS/services/2009_SJCounty_1ft_IS/ImageServer/WMSServer

You'll probably get better results if you modify the capabilities files to use the same name as your original URL (maps.sjcounty.net) - then, when ArcGIS connects to the WMS it reconnects back to the same URL to continue using the service.

Direct links are working, although image/png wasn't:

https://maps.sjcounty.net/ArcGIS/services/2009_SJCounty_1ft_IS/ImageServer/WMSServer?request=GetMap&service=WMS&format=image/png24&crs=EPSG:2259&width=200&height=200&bbox=2363751.45760155,1819175.47190285,2844489.53149986,2185723.53479958

Also, ensure that the envelopes in your capabilities file actually do surround the imagery in question.  I've noticed with ImageServer services that sometimes it selects the extent of the first image in a set rather than the extent of all images, so you'll end up getting clear graphics (white on white) where you should be getting proper pixels from your service.

Comment: Currently I'm working on just using it internally, I pushed it out externally for the XML link for this post, so I would like to keep it with the same capabilities file. Thank you.

Comment: Same advice applies when you're using it internally - make sure all the URLs are consistent.